# How to tell whether your racing game wheel is analog

Tags: windows-7, game-controller

I imagine that are two kinds of controller wheels:

1. Good, where there are multiple steering levels (analog)
2. Bad, where is there is just right or left (like a keyboard button)

How can I identify in Windows 7 which kind my steering wheel is?

Comment: Have you tried the Controllers (or whatever they call it in 7) control panel?

Comment: *> How to tell whether your racing game wheel is analog* The manual?

Comment: @Synetech I have no manual, the support page doesn't help either http://www.clone.com.br/db/detalhes_prod.asp?detalhe=06153

Comment: @Ignacio In the control panel it behaves like the bad one, but I'm fairly sure that once I was able to get multiple steering levels on a game (Shift 2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a while since I've done this, so I may not remember it exactly but try going to "Devices and Printers" from the Control Panel, the right clicking on the controller you are talking about and selecting "Game controller settings" from the menu, then clicking "Properties" on the popup window. Then all you have to do is move your wheel left to right and watch to see how the axes change. If the controller is analog (or at least digital with more than two positions) you should see the pointer or bars move smoothly.

So in summary:

1. Go to the Control Panel
2. Click on "Devices and Printers"
3. Right click on your wheel
4. Select "Game controller settings"
5. Click "Properties"
6. Turn wheel
7. Watch for movement

Comment: Have you tested it with an analog wheel?

Comment: @Jader Dias
I have done this in the past with joysticks, controllers and wheels and it has worked for all of them. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "analog" in this situation because I'm almost sure your wheel is digital, it probably has to be for the computer to be able to interpret its data. Also, if it is a wheel, it probably has more than two positions (on/off, left/right, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You could always just [ask the manufacturer](http://www.clone.com.br/db/faleconosco.asp). That’s probably the easiest, most authoritative answer you’ll get, particularly for less common hardware like this.

Answer (score -1):

Analog game controllers are thing of the past. They connect to gameport, then computer has DSP to read actual position. Modern game controllers have ADC in device.

Comment: I didn't mean that kind of analog controllers. When I say analog it means that it can detect more than three wheel positions

Comment: "major manufacturers" usually state full specs. even 20$ genius brand wheel will have accurate positions.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.